# Xcode UISegmentedControl is not showing on iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I had a *UISegementedControl* on a *UIViewController*. it shows on iOS 13+ but it is invisible on iOS 12+.

iOS 12.4

[image]

iOS 13.2.2

[image]

I tried having a fix size but still not showing.

Edit: this is the Attributes Inspector.

[image]

Comment: try adding this code on info.plist.. <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
 <string>Light</string>

Comment: @BenRockey it is still not working

Comment: can u include the attributes inspector screenshot of uisegmentedcontrol on the storyboard..

Comment: @BenRockey I updated the post

Comment: change the tint and background from default to any other colour and try..

Comment: It's showing now. Thanks @BenRockey!

Comment: You're welcome..

Comment: @BenRockey Please put it on the answer box so I can flag it as answered question. thanks again!

Comment: ok. i will add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the tint and background from default to any other colour and try..